# subscribe a newsletter

Tags: magento2, newsletter-subscriber

I noticed that on my website [agoshop.at](https://agoshop.at) my newsletter will not work.
When I insert an e-mail address I will never get an message and I cannot find any insert in any table like newsletter_subscriber.
It will created from a company which is no more available.
I find a block in the backend with the following code:

```
<form method="post">
<div class="form_search">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wp-form">
<div class="text_form">VERPASSEN SIE KEINE AKTION!</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wp-field">
<div class="form-newletter"><input class="search_input" name="input" type="text" value="" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse" /> <button class="subscribe" type="submit">Newsletter<br />Anmelden</button></div>
<div class="dsgvo"><input required="" type="checkbox" /> Ich akzeptiere die <a href="/datenschutz" target="_blank">Datenschutzbedingungen</a> von AGO-Shop.</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</form>
```

Also when I want to create a new account and press on the newsletter button I will get an error page:

Hope someone can help me there.
kindly regards

Comment: When you try to submit, any error on the console or magento log files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update Your code with below code and try

```
<form class="form subscribe" novalidate="novalidate" method="post" action="https://agoshop.at/newsletter/subscriber/new/" >
    <div class="form_search">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wp-form">
    <div class="text_form">VERPASSEN SIE KEINE AKTION!</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 wp-field">
    <div class="form-newletter"><input class="search_input" name="email" type="email" value="" placeholder="E-Mail Adresse" /> <button class="subscribe" type="submit">Newsletter<br />Anmelden</button></div>
    <div class="dsgvo"><input required="" type="checkbox" /> Ich akzeptiere die <a href="/datenschutz" target="_blank">Datenschutzbedingungen</a> von AGO-Shop.</div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

---

If still not work then you can simply use below default magento code.

```
{{block class="Magento\Newsletter\Block\Subscribe" name="static.newsletter" template="Magento_Newsletter::subscribe.phtml"}}
```